# Deletion of rows from populated table

Tags: php, html

I'm currently facing a strange issue whereby I did not get any errors from my debugging page. My table consists of several rows and only the first row of the table can't be deleted.

Sample form:

```
$DB = new PDO('sqlite:database/Sample.db');
$result = $DB->query("select * from staff");        
foreach ($result as $row)
{
    $StaffNo= $row['StaffNo'];
    $Name= $row['Name'];
    $TelNo= $row ['TelNo']; 

 echo "<tr>";
//Go to remove.php to remove
echo "<form action=\"Remove.php\" method=\"post\">";
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"StaffNo\" value=\"$StaffNo\">";
echo "<input type=\"submit\" onclick=\"return confirm('Yes/No')\"/>";
echo "</form>";
 echo "</td>";
echo '<td data-column-name="Name" char="data">'.$Name.'</td>';
echo '<td data-column-name="TelNo" char="data">'.$TelNo.'</td>';
</tr>
}
```

Remove.php:

```
$StaffNo= $_POST["StaffNo"];
$DB = new PDO('sqlite:database/Sample.db');

$DB->query("DELETE FROM Staff WHERE StaffNo=".$StaffNo);

@header("location:view.php");
```

From my code above, I can delete all my sample records except for the first row. It doesn't get deleted... Kindly advise if i did wrong somewhere....

Comment: Probably you just didn't send that 'StaffNo'. try outputting each 'StaffNo' sent to Remove.php

Comment: I tried. It can delete all the rows except for the first row.

Comment: Is the misplaced `}` (right now, `$staffNo` is getting overwritten every loop iteration) and the missing `echo` statements around `<tr>` there due to a copy-paste error, or is it there in your real code as well? The bug may be in the part(s) you omitted.

Comment: @RikkusRukkus I have edited my error. Its my typing mistakes. Please advise if I have made any more errors

Comment: Output the query from the php script and try running it in mysql client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried your code and apart from the broken table code, everything seems fine. Make sure your table is correct (`<table><tr><td>Content</td></tr></table>`). In your question, you're missing an opening `<td>` on line 9 of the first file, as well as missing `<table>` tags. Some browsers don't handle broken tables very well and that might mess up your form.

Your query will also break if `$StaffNo` is an empty string, so double check that.

You can also try removing the `header()` call and print out errors using `$DB->errorInfo()`.

Answer (score 0):

To inject your variable i the hidden field you should type 
    ".$StaffNo." 
instead of 
    "$StaffNo".
probably it doesn't delete the first row of your table becouse it's the only one with a StaffNo defined.

Comment: He's using double quotes, so variables will be interpreted. If he used single quotes, he would indeed need something like `value="'. $StaffNo .'"`. Using double quotes, `value=\"$StaffNo\"` is enough.